# Resizing Awesomium WebView does not resize surface

Tags: c#, awesomium

I'm using awesomium to take a snapshot of an HTML page.

```
public Bitmap renderHtml(string htmlContent)
    {
        using (WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(WebPreferences.Default))
        {
            int docHeight = 0, docWidth = 0;
            using (WebView view = WebCore.CreateWebView(1, 1, WebViewType.Offscreen))
            {

                bool finishedLoading = false;
                var uri = new Uri("data:text/html," + htmlContent, UriKind.Absolute);
                //uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
                view.Source = uri;
                view.LoadingFrameComplete += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.IsMainFrame)
                        {
                            finishedLoading = true;
                            docHeight = (int)view.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("(function() { var bodyElmnt = document.body; var html = document.documentElement; var height = Math.max( bodyElmnt.scrollHeight, bodyElmnt.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight ); return height; })();");
                            docWidth = (int)view.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("(function() { var bodyElmnt = document.body; var html = document.documentElement; var width = Math.max( bodyElmnt.scrollWidth, bodyElmnt.offsetWidth, html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth); return width; })();");
                        }
                    };
                while (!finishedLoading)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    WebCore.Update();
                }
                //view.Surface.Initialize(view, docWidth, docHeight);
                view.Resize(docWidth, docHeight);

                //cannot do this here because view.Surface size is (1,1)
                /*
                bmp = new Bitmap(docWidth, docHeight);
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
                BitmapSurface bmpSurface = (BitmapSurface)view.Surface;
                bmpSurface.CopyTo(bmpData.Scan0, bmpSurface.RowSpan, 4, false, false);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                */ 
            }
            using (WebView view2 = WebCore.CreateWebView(docWidth, docHeight, WebViewType.Offscreen))
            {
                bool finishedLoading = false;
                var uri = new Uri("data:text/html," + htmlContent, UriKind.Absolute);

                view2.Source = uri;
                view2.LoadingFrameComplete += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.IsMainFrame)
                    {
                        finishedLoading = true;
                    }
                };
                while (!finishedLoading)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    WebCore.Update();
                }
                bmp = new Bitmap(docWidth, docHeight);
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
                BitmapSurface bmpSurface = (BitmapSurface)view2.Surface;
                bmpSurface.CopyTo(bmpData.Scan0, bmpSurface.RowSpan, 4, false, false);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

            }
        }

        return bmp;
    }
```

This works, but I need to create a second view using the page size that I got from the first view because when I call view.Resize() it does not resize the view's Surface so i'm getting an error trying to save the image because the sizes differ. If I call Surface.Initialize first with the new width and height then the original surface is gone and all I get is an empty white image.

How can I resize the view's surface and make this work without creating a 2nd view ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use your WebView's Surface right after you resize your WebView since it takes some time for it to resize, update and redraw. The update is done asynchronously, so you should wait for Surface.Resized event to happen. Try something like that:

```
using (var vw = WebCore.CreateWebView(100,100))
{
    vw.Source = new Uri("website");
    while (vw.IsLoading)
    {
        WebCore.Update();
    }
    var surface = (BitmapSurface)vw.Surface;
    surface.SaveToPNG("screen1.png");
    surface.Resized += (s, e) =>
    {
        // Save the updated buffer to a new PNG image.
        surface.SaveToPNG("screen2.png");
        WebCore.Shutdown();
    };

    var x = vw.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.body.scrollWidth").ToString();
    var y = vw.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.body.scrollHeight").ToString();
    vw.Resize(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));

    WebCore.Run();
}
```

This snippet of code will open a website, take a screenshot, then resize your webview, wait for Resized to fire and take another screenshot.

Hope that helps.